# Как удалить html теги и сохранить в csv только текст в BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Написал минипарсер новостного сайта, но при сохранении тела статьи в текст добавляются html теги, хотя название статьи сохраняется отлично. Помогите удалить эти теги посредством BeautifulSoup (если возможно). Голову сломал, пока читал документацию bs4.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req
from datetime import datetime
import re
import csv


def get_html(url):
    resp = req.get(url) 
    return resp.text                         

def get_all_links(html): 
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    parse = soup.find('div', class_='col left-col').find_all('a')
    links = []
    for i in parse:
        result = i.get('href')
        if len(result) < 17:
            link = 'https://ura.news' + result
            links.append(link)
        else: 
            continue
    return links

def get_page_data(html):  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    try:
        title = soup.find('div', class_='publication').find('h1').text.strip()
    except:
        title = ''
    try:
        article = soup.find('div', itemprop='articleBody').find_all('p')
    except:
        article = ''
    data = {'title': title,
            'article': article}
    return data


def write_csv(data):
    with open ('uranews.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow((data['title'], data['article']))
        print(data['title'], '- записана')


def main():
    start = datetime.now()
    url = 'https://ura.news'
    all_links = get_all_links( get_html(url) )
    for url in all_links:
        html = get_html(url)
        data = get_page_data(html)
        write_csv(data)


    end = datetime.now()
    total = end - start
    print(str(total))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Результат:

```
Глава Керчи и ее подчиненные уволились после скандала с раздачей хлеба блокадникам,"[<p>Глава Керченского горсовета Мая Хужина и ее заместитель Лариса Щербула написали заявление об увольнении. Заявления последовали после того, как чиновницы «в шубах» раздали ветеранам-блокадникам медали и «символический хлеб». </p>, <p>Как сообщается в Telegram-канале «Единой России», партия добилась отставки керченских чиновниц. «Дамы написали заявление по собственному желанию. Справедливое решение. Хватит уже такого „хлеба“ и таких „зрелищ“», — сказано в сообщении.</p>, <p>«Заявление об отставке мной написано, но окончательное решение за депутатами городского совета, так как это именно они выбирали меня на данную ответственную и высокую должность», — приводит РИА «Новости» слова Хужиной.</p>, <p>После того как фотоснимки, на которых чиновницы в дорогих шубах раздают ветеранам хлеб, разошлись по интернету, глава Крыма Сергей Аксенов заявил, что подобные люди не должны и не будут возглавлять органы власти, напоминает <a href=""https://russian.rt.com/russia/news/713673-aksyonov-krym-uvolnenie-chinovniki"" target=""_blank"">RT</a>.</p>, <p>Хужина на своей странице в Facebook позже <a href=""https://ura.news/news/1052416830"" target=""_blank"">пыталась оправдаться</a>, что они были одеты «не в шубы, а в имитацию». Однако позже она удалила этот пост. </p>, <p></p>]"
```

Желаемый результат:

```
Глава Керчи и ее подчиненные уволились после скандала с раздачей хлеба блокадникам,"Глава Керченского горсовета Мая Хужина и ее заместитель Лариса Щербула написали заявление об увольнении. Заявления последовали после того, как чиновницы «в шубах» раздали ветеранам-блокадникам медали и «символический хлеб». Как сообщается в Telegram-канале «Единой России», партия добилась отставки керченских чиновниц. «Дамы написали заявление по собственному желанию. Справедливое решение. Хватит уже такого „хлеба“ и таких „зрелищ“», — сказано в сообщении. «Заявление об отставке мной написано, но окончательное решение за депутатами городского совета, так как это именно они выбирали меня на данную ответственную и высокую должность», — приводит РИА «Новости» слова Хужиной. После того как фотоснимки, на которых чиновницы в дорогих шубах раздают ветеранам хлеб, разошлись по интернету, глава Крыма Сергей Аксенов заявил, что подобные люди не должны и не будут возглавлять органы власти, напоминает Хужина на своей странице в Facebook позже пыталась оправдаться, что они были одеты «не в шубы, а в имитацию». Однако позже она удалила этот пост."
```

Пробовал использовать различные методы из библиотеки BeautifulSoup в функции get_page_data, но желаемого результата не достиг. Благодарю за помощь заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить функцию `get_page_data`

```
def get_page_data(html):  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    try:
        title = soup.find('div', class_='publication').find('h1').text.strip()
    except:
        title = ''
    try:
        article = soup.find('div', itemprop='articleBody').find_all('p')  
        ob = ''                                                           # +++
        for art in article:                                               # +++
            ob += art.text + '\n'                                         # +++
    except:
        article = ''
    data = {'title': title,
            'article': ob}                                                # - article   +  ob
    return data
```